# How to call values by column name after reading in CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have read in a csv by saving each element of a row to the listed column name variables.

For example:

```
data = []

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        col1, col2, col3 = line.split('\t')
        data.append([col1, col2, col3])
```

Now, if I want to perform some operation on a specific column in `data`, such as `col1`, how could I do that?

The below code does not work:

```
for line in data:
    print(col1)
```

Instead, I would need to hardcode the line element in question, likeso:

```
for line in data:
    print(line[0])
```

I thought that because I read the csv in a way that I defined `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` that I should be able to call upon the elements of my list that correspond to these column names.

Is it possible to do this? I do not want to use imported modules/packages (like pandas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined the variables `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` within a specific scope of your script—within the `for` loop—and outside of that section of code, you cannot access these variables. Here are two suggestions I have:

1. The quickest way to perform a manipulation of your column data might be to insert a statement before you do `data.append()`. In other words, if you wanted to add 5 to column 2, you could do something like this:

```
data = []

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        col1, col2, col3 = line.split('\t')

        col2 += 5  # Modify column before appending

        data.append([col1, col2, col3])
```

2. If you need all of the data to be collected first, and then you'd like to modify it afterward in a different step, you can start another `for` loop. Keep in mind that you have now doubled the amount of time that your script will run (you loop over the data twice instead of once). You can use a Python grammar feature called "list unpacking" to get your column variables back, like so:

```
data = []

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        col1, col2, col3 = line.split('\t')
        data.append([col1, col2, col3])

modified_data = []

for row in data:
    col1, col2, col3 = row  # This is list unpacking
    
    . . .  # (do something with columns here)

    modified_data.append([col1, col2, col3])
```

Comment: Would it be possible (after list unpacking) to iterate over the defined variables? ie, ```for col1 in data: ```

Comment: @matriz You could definitely continue to iterate deeper, but only if `col1` was also a list. For example, if you had a nested (2D) list of values such as `[['a', 'b'], 2, 3]` then you could use a `for` loop to iterate over `col1`. (`col1 == ['a', 'b']` after such unpacking). But if all you want to do is to modify one of those columns, you don't need a deeper `for` loop—just modify it and append it to the `modified_data` list. CAVEAT: You can also iterate over strings, so don't get fooled. If you do `for x in 'hello'`, the variable `x` will iterate over `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, and then `o`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you want to avoid Pandas, which is not part of the standard library.

I ***always*** recommend using CSV libraries for parsing CSV files, though, and Python's standard library includes a CSV module which has the **DictReader** class which is what you're looking for:

```py
import csv

data = []

with open('sample.txt', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')

    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

# ... and later

for datum in data:
    print(datum['this_column'])
    print(datum['that_column'])
```